# Не показывать повторно межстраничную рекламу

Tags: android, admob

Есть активити в котором в методе onCreate я вывожу межстраничную рекламу. Все было вроде хорошо приложение в маркете уже пол года. Но пару часов назад пришло письмо от гугл что типа межстраничная реклама не должна показываться во время просмотра контента. Что это может означать? В активити также создаются уведомления и если нажать на уведомление опять открывается реклама и опять показывается межстраничная реклама. Может это имелось ввиду?

Вот текста письма

```
РАЗМЕЩЕНИЕ МЕЖСТРАНИЧНЫХ ОБЪЯВЛЕНИЙ, ПРОВОЦИРУЮЩЕЕ СЛУЧАЙНЫЕ КЛИКИ
Издателям не разрешается создавать ситуации, в которых пользователи могут непреднамеренно нажать на межстраничные объявления AdMob. Межстраничные объявления не должны:

загружаться, когда пользователь просматривает контент.
```

В каком месте лучше выводить рекламу межстраничную? Я во всех приложенииям в методе onCreate вывожу

```
Intent PlayerIntent;
private InterstitialAd adMob;

public void displayAdMob() {
    if (adMob.isLoaded()) {
        adMob.show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            PlayerIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player.class);
            PlayerIntent.putExtra("stream", stream);
            displayAdMob();
        }
    });


    adMob = new InterstitialAd(this);
    adMob.setAdUnitId("ID");
    // Создаём запрос к AdMob
    AdRequest adRequesti = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    // Начинаем загружать объявление
    adMob.loadAd(adRequesti);
    adMob.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            startActivity(PlayerIntent);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: ИМХО это значит, что нельзя вводить пользователя в заблуждение. Типа ставить ссылку на крестик, который якобы закрывает рекламу и.т.п.

Comment: Согласен, но у меня такого нет

Comment: Просто объявление выводится и все

Comment: Есть открыть активити и сразу нажать на кнопку домой то межстраничная реклама всплывает прям на рабочий стол. Может с этим связано замечание? Если да, то как сделать так чтобы реклама отображалась только тогда открыто само активити? Т.е. когда активити прям на экране

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно они расценили это так:

Открылась `Activity`, начинает показывать контент и тут же вылазит реклама - значит преднамеренно для накрутки кликов.

Перенесите из `onCreate` туда, откуда запускаете эту `Activity`, т.е. покажите сначала рекламу. А после того как пользователь ее закроет, в `onAdClosed()`,  уже переходите на эту `Activity`.

---

При нажатии замените на показ рекламы (предварительно перенесите ее создание и подгрузку в Ваш MainActivity):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        displayAdMob();
    }
});
```

И после закрытия переходите на нужную  Activity:

```
adMob.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Player.class);
        intent.putExtra("stream", stream);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Эта активити запускается из MainActivity. Значит мне нужно в MainActivity добавить показ рекламы?

Comment: Есть пример простенький?

Comment: @Scorpion покажите как Вы запускаете

Comment: В вопрос добавил код. Первая часть кода до метода displayAdMob у меня в методе onCreate

Comment: @Scorpion я имел в виду Activity, а не рекламу

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: @Scorpion обновил ответ

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Так имелось ввиду?